# Why is window.open blocked while changing window.location.href is fine?

Tags: javascript

When the running javascript code is triggered by non-user events (timer, ajax ready, etc.), `window.open` is blocked (in chrome there will be a popup blocker in the url bar).

But changing `window.location.href` works fine.

I'm wondering why this decision is made. Are there any spec about this? (I only tested on chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is trying to open a popup, which people find distracting so browser developers block it.

The other is simply navigating the current page - which would make no sense to block as without that functionality standard links would not work.

Comment: Does that mean main issue was distraction and user annoyance rather than security?

Comment: @Pixel - just opening a popup window is no more insecure than navigating to a page.